# Probability of a point taken from a certain normal distribution will be less than or equal to than a point taken from another?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, probability, normal-distribution

Suppose we have two independent normal distributions
[image]

How do I calculate the probability of a certain point taken from distribution X1 being `less than or equal to` a certain point taken from distribution X2 in Python?

With reference to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40224/probability-of-a-point-taken-from-a-certain-normal-distribution-will-be-greater) I can say that the formula for `greater than` could be something like this,

Example,

```
m1, std1 = 1, 2 
m2, std2 = 2, 3

#then,
```

[image]

and,
[image]

```
# hence, 
from scipy.stats import norm
p = 1 - norm.cdf(-(m1 - m2) / np.sqrt(std1 + std2))
# p = 0.32736042300928847
```

I am looking for the code for [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let Y be X₁ - X₂.  You've already shown that
Y ~ N(μ₁ - μ₂, σ₁² + σ₂²).
You want P(Y ≤ 0). That is the [CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) of Y evaluated at 0.

In code:

```
from math import sqrt
from scipy.stats import norm

m1, std1 = 1, 2
m2, std2 = 2, 3

m = m1 - m2
std = sqrt(std1**2 + std2**2)
print(norm.cdf(0, loc=m, scale=std))
```

Output is

```
0.6092443525006433
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they have the same mean l, the probability will be 50%.the distribution is irrelevant. So best in this context normalise the distributions so they have the same mean.

Comment: I did not get how you arrived at 50%. Note the parameters `m1, std1 = 1, 2 
m2, std2 = 2, 3` are experimental, `std1, std2` can take any values, `0.0236, .63` etc. Can you elaborate your answer in python code?